# Css set border none to last table tr

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have this below css code to set border on all `td` :

```
table td {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #706E6D;
    direction: rtl;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

i want to set `border:none;` to last tr (this may have any `td`).

```
table tr:last-child  {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying to border rules to `td` elements. So you also need to remove it from `td` of last `tr` itself like this.

```
table tr:last-child td  {
    border: none;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rZ3eM/)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want all of the table **cells** in the last row to have no border. Change your CSS rule to:

```
table tr:last-child td {
    border: none;
}
```